# The geometry of a transformation given by a singular $2\times 2$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If you have a singular $2\times 2$ matrix, I understand geometrically both the row picture and the column picture of why there are either $0$ or infinitely many solutions. But in terms of linear transformations, I have not yet grasped if there is anything about the geometry of the transformation the matrix applies to a $2D$ vector which intuitively confirms the fact the rows/columns are linearly dependent. Is there intuition for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Briefly, if $A$ is a real $2 \times 2$ matrix that is non-zero and not invertible, the image of the associated linear transformation is a line $\ell$. The linear system $A\Vec{x} = \Vec{b}$ has infinitely many solutions if $\Vec{b}$ lies on $\ell$, and has no solutions if $\Vec{b}$ does not lie on $\ell$.

Algebraically, there exist non-zero vectors $\Vec{v}$ (unique up to multiplication by a non-zero scalar) and $\Vec{u}$ (uniquely determined by $A$ and $\Vec{v}$) such that $A = \Vec{v} \Vec{u}^{\mathsf{T}}$. The line $\ell$ is spanned by $\Vec{v}$, and the null space of $A$ is the line orthogonal to $\Vec{u}$. (Proving this is a pleasant exercise.)

Comment: You beat me to it ... GRRRR ...

Comment: @Carl: If you've already typed up ideas that don't overlap completely, I'd be happy to upvote if you post them. :) (To my mind, a "first-post-takes-all" culture encourages hastily-written, incomplete, or even erroneous answers, which I see as contrary to the site's mission. In my view, it's worthwhile to write carefully and to forego upvoting answers that appear not to be written carefully, even if they technically precede other answers.)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Actually, I was going to say basically what you did, including the decomposition of $A$.